# Is it possible to see `messages` sent from a process and the destination of those messages?

Tags: c#, windows, process, messaging

*Apologize in advance if the wording of my question is bad, wasn't sure exactly what to ask*

I have a c# app that is supposed to receive messages from a different app running. Here's a short snippet of my receiver code:

```
private static IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
     if (msg == WM_THREADTT2NSDONE)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("received message");
     }
     return IntPtr.Zero;
 }
```

The code works and receives messages, but isn't receiving any from the app. The problem is, I have no idea what the other app is looking for when it's sending these messages out. The source code is not available for it.

I DO have the app's process ID, it's Handle, and everything else that is returned when I use `Process.GetProcessesByName("SendingAppHere");`

Is there any way to find what 'messages' are being sent by the app and the supposed destination of those messages?

Comment: Spy++ (spyxx.exe) ships with visual studio, that can display realtime window message traffic.

Comment: Awesome! Didn't know about this. Checking it out now.